# Twisted WSGI server fail to authenticate client

Tags: python, ssl, flask, twisted, wsgi

Using Flask API framework (Windows) and Twisted WSGI server, I am able to launch a TLS server that clients can authenticate.  However, when I add client verification the server fails to authenticate with a SSL bad handshake error.

When using the Flask development server the 2 way authentication works fine.
Any advice on how to fix or debug.

See code snippets below.

**Server**

```
srv_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('srv.crt', 'r').read())
srv_privKey = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('srv_pKey.pem', 'r').read())
ca_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,open('User_caChain.crt', 'r').read())
ssl_ctx = ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=srv_privKey,
                                 certificate=srv_cert,
                                 verify=True,
                                 caCerts=[ca_cert])

https_server = endpoints.SSL4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 
                                            port=5001, 
                                            interface='myHost', 
                                            sslContextFactory=ssl_ctx)
# start server
resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), app)
site = server.Site(resource)
https_server.listen(site)
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
reactor.run()
```

**Client**

```
import requests
verify='Srv_caChain.crt'
cert=('user.crt', 'user_pKey.pem')

url = 'https://%s:5001/hi' % (socket.gethostname()) 

res = requests.get(url, verify=verify, cert=cert) 
print res.status_code, res.content
```

**Flask**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hi')
def hiMom():    
    s = "HI MOM!!!! %i %s %s " % (app.r, app.u, app.p)
    resp = Response(response=s,
                    status=200,
                    mimetype="application/json")
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ssl_ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain('srv.crt', 'srv_pKey.pem')
    ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    ssl_ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile='User_Inter01_caChain.crt')

    app.run(host='myHost', port=5001, ssl_context=ssl_ctx, 
                    threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: What is the exact SSL error?  If it doesn't include an SSL error code or OpenSSL error information, switch to a client that does report this (try `openssl s_client`)?

Comment: I receive SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')  I also tested the certificates with Apache which worked fine.  I also verified the chain with OpenSSl  thanks

Comment: That doesn't include an SSL error code.  It just says the connection closed.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all I got is there a way to get more debug information from twisted?